# Couldn't install ubuntu on my phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch

well, i have a nexus 4 and tryed to install the ubuntu on it with the Manual Download & Installation, but when i try to do this: fastboot flash system trusty-preinstalled-system-armel+mako.img. its says "FAILED "
what could be happening ?

Answer (score 0):

i assume that you were installing it on mako directly off google's occam stock firmware? at this stage, there are not much details are available but i reckon that there will be more soon. by giving as much information on your experience and challenges, hopefully the rate of its development will speed up and producing more resources available to all.
please share with the forum more details such as screen capture specific model/built/root and the step/methods used leading up to the error message. also, let us know if you are able to factory restore your device or is it bricked and completely broken. screen capture would be great too - i find it easier to study or diagnose and troubleshoot with pretty funky graphics. 
there are so much to be learned from your techno-adventure and i hope that you find the solution that you are looking for.